# How to truncate number to first eight digits?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro that truncates extra digits from the end of an 8 digit account number.

I've tried using different types of loops.

```
'Asks how many entries then inputs it into FOR loop
entryNum = InputBox("Number of Entries: ", "Account Number Truncator")

For counter = 2 To entryNum
    acctCor = Len(Cells(counter, 1))
    While acctCor > 8 'Loop to check the length of the number and then removes the last erroneous digits
        Cells(counter, 1).Value = Left(Cells(counter, 1), Len(Cells(counter, 1)) - 1) 'This is the part that's supposed to truncate the number
        acctCor = Len(Cells(counter, 1))
    Wend
Next counter
```

Numbers like 547890012508973240987 get converted into 5478.900 when it is supposed to be 54789001 and it only seems to work on numbers with lesser digits.

Comment: You know that you can round numbers just like `Round(Number, 8)` being 8 the number of decimals?

Comment: What are the *types* of your variables? If you don't want unwanted type conversions, don't use the default variant type which you get if you don't declare your variables.

Comment: Didnt know I could, issue is the numbers have to be the exact first 8 digits. would that look like Cells(counter, 1).Value = Round(Cells(counter, 1), 8) ?

Comment: @Damian - there are no decimals in the source "numbers"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Left() instead of chopping off digits one by one:

```
entryNum = InputBox("Number of Entries: ", "Account Number Truncator") 'Asks how many entries then inputs it into FOR loop
For counter = 2 To entryNum
    With Cells(counter, 1)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = Left(.Value,8)
    End With
Next counter
```

Also - be very careful with numbers in Excel if you're not planning to use them as actual numbers (ie. they're just identifiers - you're not going to be doing any math on them)

For example 547890012508973240987 is beyond the limit of Excel's 15-digit precision.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/long-numbers-incorrectly-in-excel

https://superuser.com/questions/413226/why-does-excel-treat-long-numeric-strings-as-scientific-notation-even-after-chan

Comment: Much appreciated it appears that your information regarding 15-digit precision is the main culprit but I definitely implemented the portion of your code. Ill likely just have the macro check for any numbers 15 digits+ and have it advise the user to manual correct those lines if it comes up.

Comment: It will not be a problem as long as you format your cells as `Text`

Comment: Ill give it a try though the reason why im not just making a formula that will do this is because we use some automation software that pulls data from this sheet and then puts it into an old iSeries system which can be finicky.